# Hide page numbering but retain header/footer

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I would like to remove page numbering on a specific page. However, the header and footer should remain intact. If I try:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

The header and footer disappear. What is the recommended way of removing just the page number?

Comment: You have to define a new page style with your required properties. Than you can use `\thispagestyle{mypagestyle}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel thanks, I have looked into that. But there is no single command to just remove page numbering then?

Comment: You can call some commands like `cfoot` inside the document. E.g. `\def\nofoot{\cfoot{}}` and `\def\withfoot{\cfoot{\thepage}}`: Now you can call `\nofoot` on pages with no footer. But you have to activate the footer on the next page with `\withfoot`.

Comment: Great, thanks! I found just using `\cfoot{}` works for my purpose. Could you provide this as an answer to accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard page style doesn't allow disappearing only the footer. However I can imagine two possibilities.

1. You can define your own page style with the required header and without any footer. This new defined page style can be used with `\thispagestyle`.
2. On the other hand you can use declaration commands of the footer (e.g. `\cfoot`)  inside the document body. If you want to suppress the footer on a page your can do `\cfoot{}`. Be aware that you have to activate the footer on the next page with `\cfoot{\thepage}`. You can simplify the process by definition two new commands: `\def\nofoot{\cfoot{}}` and `\def\withfoot{\cfoot{\thepage}}`.

Comment: How to use `\cfoot{}` for page containing large floating table?

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}               % Uses the fancyheadr package
\fancyhf[L]{\underline{MYCONTENT}}  % Above justifies Left in header and footer "MYCONTENT".
\fancyfoot[C]{}                     % Removes the page number from Center of the footer.
```

As learned from the documentation of `fancyhdr` package dated January 31, 2019.
I hope this helps.